# SAS Macro Rename Variables

Tags: macros, sas

I have a macro I’m trying to write....
X1-X50

But I want to rename the variable to 
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 and so on all the way to E5.

X1 - X5 will be A1- A5
X6 - X10 will be B1 - B5 and so on.

How do I rename the variables with a macro in SAS?

Comment: so do you mean you have variables x1-x50 and want it  to be change.

Comment: your question is confusing, can you provide more details, exactly what you have and what are trying to get to.

Comment: `X50` would mean you would need 10 groups of 5, prefaced with  `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J`.  what should happen if the # in `X#` is greater than 130 = (26 letters in groups of 5)

Comment: Please show an example. Even if you don’t know where to start, show an example of the rename statement you want to generate. For example, maybe you want a macro that would be called like %rename(var=x1-x50) that would generate `rename x1=A1 X2=A2 ... X6=B1 ... X50=J5;` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a data set with the old name and new name in two columns

   ```
   data names;
   letter=64;
   counter=0;

   do i=1 to 50;
       counter=ifn(counter=5, 1, counter+1);

       if mod(i, 5)=1 then
           do;
               letter+1;
               letter_char=byte(letter);
           end;
       old=catt('X', put(i, 2. -l));
       new=catt(letter_char, counter);
       output;
   end;
   run;
   ```
2. Create a macro variable that has the old and new names in the form of old = new, for all variables, ie X1=A1 X2=A2  X6=B1...etc.

   ```
   proc sql;
   select catx(' = ', old, new) into :rename_list separated by " "
   from names;
    quit;
   ```
3. Apply the rename statement within PROC DATASETS - this changes the data but does not do a full pass of the data.

   ```
   proc datasets lib=work;
   modify dataSetName;
   rename &rename_list.;
   run;quit;
   ```